# How make a smooth scrollable textview?

Tags: android, textview, scrollable

I have a textview in my application with a vertical scroll. Goes well but without any "animation" so it's not very beautiful to see. How can i implement the smooth animation? If needs:

the java:

```
TextView textscroll = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textscroll);
            textscroll.setText(getCPUinfo());
            textscroll.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

And the xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/CPUinfo"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:maxLines="10"
    tools:ignore="SelectableText" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making Your TexView a child of a ScrollView!

```
<ScrollView>
    <TextView>
    </TextView>
</ScrollView>
```

Just like that. Your Text should be Scrolling as any other scrollable Android application You know with the classical blue or orange light when reaching the end of the TextView.

Comment: I don't know why but for me this method doesn't go :(